# Android device current location without Internet

Tags: android, android-location

Without any Internet connection, can the `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` still provide the location because of the cell tower?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. NETWORK_PROVIDER sends information about cell towers (or WiFi hotspots) via the Internet.

[Quote from docs:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#NETWORK_PROVIDER)

> Results are retrieved by means of a network lookup.

Comment: what does by means of network lookup ??? means? Sorry my english is not super good.

Comment: As I understand, "network lookup" means "request over the network [Internet]". I'm not native English speaker, too :)